# AWS S3 to Glacier: did backup work?

Tags: amazon-s3, lifecycle, amazon-glacier

I am experimenting with backing up data in my Amazon S3 folders to Glacier using lyfecycle management options. I chose one of the folders in the bucket for the testing and created a lifecycle rule that states that objects with that prefix need to be migrated to Glacier after 30 days. I created the rule today but these files are all older than 30 days so I expected them to get migrated right away. But I am looking at that S3 folder and not noticing any changes. How do I find out if a backup actually occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifecycle management policy (LMP) you applied will affect all items matching it, whether they existed before you applied the policy or were created after you applied it.  It takes time for the policy to synchronize across all of your items in S3.  See [Object Lifecycle Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) just before and after "Before You Decide to Archive Objects".

The objects moved by a LMP are only visible through the S3 API, not via the Glacier API or console.  You'll continue to see the objects listed in your S3 bucket, but the object's metadata will be updated to indicate that the `x-amz-storage-class` is Glacier.  You should be able to see this through the S3 console, or by making a request for the object's metadata using the S3 API.  See [Object Key and Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) for the `System-Defined Metadata`.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like the S3 management console also shows "Storage Class" as a column for easy review.  For me, it shows "Standard" for S3 and "Glacier" for Glacier.